# ECRYPT Salsa20 Test Vectors Interpretation

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher, initialization-vector, salsa20, test-vectors

I am currently implementing Salsa20 for my bachelor thesis. After having verified all the functions needed for the final encryption function with the given test data in [the specification from DJB](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/spec.pdf), I wanted to test my encryption function. Unfortunately, there are no test vectors for the full encryption in the specification paper:

I have found test vectors for Salsa20/20 from the ECRYPT Stream cipher project [here](https://github.com/das-labor/legacy/blob/master/microcontroller-2/arm-crypto-lib/testvectors/salsa20-256.64-verified.test-vectors).

But for some reason, the first 64-byte sequence matches with the output of my expansion function with the given key and IV and counter set to 0, **but the second 64-byte sequence differs.**

Actual:

```
0xa360370ff47dd714684fd47584e46fe89e031b59072be978f7c0a56936151a3e9c52f7be26c687a5bc234640efed47b79b02d70dd666dc39cea9288e69427318
```

Expected:

```
0x57be81f47b17d9ae7c4ff15429a73e10acf250ed3a90a93c711308a74c6216a9ed84cd126da7f28e8abf8bb63517e1ca98e712f4fb2e1a6aed9fdc73291faa17
```

I have used the IV 0x0 (64-bit) and counter 0x1 (64-bit) concatenated such that the nonce given to the expansion function is

```
0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
```

(big endian). But this leads to an incorrect result as shown above.

I have tried to write the bytes of the counter in littleendian since the specification paper mentions this in the last section about encryption:

```
0x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

but that only lead to a different wrong result:

```
0x8da2b74eef1b6283e7e20166abcae538e9716e4669e2816b6b20c5c356802001cc1403a9a117d12a2669f456366d6ebb0f1246f1265150f793cdb4b253e348ae
```

**I am assuming that I have misinterpreted the test data since my expansion function passes all the tests with the test data given in the specs.**

I found out [here](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/perf/#overview) that the test vectors use the NESSIE format but could not explain the data that solves my problem (probably there is no explanation because I am doing something entirely wrong).

**I am also confused about what "(stream is generated by encrypting 512 zero bytes)" should mean. The stream is independent of the plaintext; thus, I wonder what they mean by saying it "is generated by encrypting 512 zero bytes"?**

I would be very glad if anyone could help or lead me in the right direction since I have been stuck with this for quite some days already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "different wrong result" (based on a **littleendian** counter) appears to be the correct *second* 64-byte sequence.  The test vector shows "stream[192..255] = ", which is the *fourth* 64-byte sequence.  The test vector is generated by calling "the Salsa20 encryption function" (Section 10 of the spec) on 512 zero bytes using the indicated key and IV.

Comment: Oh, wow, I should have noticed this myself... Thank you so much, that solved my problem!